# EF Code first Keyword not supported: 'provider'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm attempting to dynamically provide database credentials to my EF model. The below approach has worked in the past when using Database First. There are several similar SO questions however none seem to resolve this issue. What am I missing here?

```
private const string ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient";

var SqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder {
    DataSource = this.ServerName,
    InitialCatalog = this.DatabaseName,
    IntegratedSecurity = true
};
var EntityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder {
    Provider = ProviderName,
    ProviderConnectionString = SqlConnectionStringBuilder.ToString()
};
using(var db = new AuditingContext(EntityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString())) 
{
    var session = new Session() {
    };
    db.Sessions.Add(session);
    //ArgumentException occurs here
    //Keyword not supported: 'provider'.
}
```

The DbContext

```
public class AuditingContext: DbContext {
    public DbSet <Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet <Cause> Causes { get; set; }
    public AuditingContext(string connectionStringName): base(connectionStringName) {}
}
```

The connection string

```
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TEST_DATABASE;Integrated Security=True\"
```

Comment: I do not think DbContext of EF5+ does expect an entity connection string, but rather an ordinary connection string.

Comment: As simple as that. Thank you very much @DevilSuichiro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by DevilSuichiro, the DbContext for EF5+ is a connection string and not [EntityConnectionString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). This resolves the issue.

```
var connString = "provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TEST_DATABASE;Integrated Security=True\"";
using(var db = new AuditingContext(connString)) 
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a console application to test the Code First approach with Sql Server 2016. 
My initial connectionString was :

```
add name="MyCodeFirstDb" connectionString="
Data Source=MyServer;
Initial Catalog=MyCodeFirstDb;
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
Auto Translate=False;"
```

I put my "connectionStrings" section after the "entityFramework" section.

The error I got when creating a linq query was :

> "Keyword provider not recognized"

I removed "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;"

I then got the error :

> "Keyword auto-translate not recognized"

I removed "AutoTranslate=False;"

I was then able to run the query and my database was created.

Answer (score -1):

use Like that

```
<add name="TerminalA" connectionString="Data 
Source=192.168.1.104;Database=ABC;Integrated Security=false;User 
ID=sa;Password=pass@123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```